# Is there any way to upload videos on Keystone JS?

Tags: javascript, video, file-upload, content-management-system, keystonejs

I need to play videos on my Keystone JS project. I'm actually uploading the videos manually and adding it by html static code, but I need to upload them from the administration panel. I was looking on the Keystone guides, but theres only a way like file type. So, is there any way to upload videos on Keystone Js?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for posting more focused question.

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Videos are just files... unless you are linking from a streaming platform.

If local-file then you could just upload the file and use that to create the player on the front end.

If from a streaming platform then just ad the ID or link and use that to create the player on the front end.